# How to refresh page using c# int every five minutes?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to refresh page using c# in every five minutes in `ASP.NET`?

Comment: You cannot push content from the server every so often, you can only pull from the client (browser).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the following HTML meta tag in your header `<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="300">` should do the trick

Comment: Yes,This is oneway, but i want from c#

Comment: Once your page is downloaded to the client, the server request is complete. There is no C# executing on the client and since the client has to initiate the refresh, AFAIK  - you can only do it with HTML / Javascript.

Comment: why?  For the server, where the C# is run, to initiate the refresh it would need to maintain a socket (ala HTML5 Web Sockets or long polling/Comet).  If it's just a page refresh, those techniques are over-engineering IMHO.

Comment: Response.AddHeder("Refresh","5"); we can do like this also , i am not sure this correct

Answer (score 7):

One is Javascript:

```
setTimeout("location.reload(true);", timeout);
```

The second is a Meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
```

Comment: Thanks Hans for editing the answer , itried here to edit but not become through well

Comment: Response.AddHeder("Refresh","5"); we can do like this also , i am not sure this correct

Answer (score 2):

You can't force an HTML page to refresh from the server side.  The client must request the page.

The only ways to do this always involve either using the META refresh tag, the Refresh HTTP header, or else javascript which forces a page reload on an interval.

Any "server-side" solution will do it by either writing javascript or the META tag to the page.  There's simply no other way to do it.

Comment: Response.AddHeder("Refresh","5"); we can do like this also , i am not sure this correct

Comment: Almost.  Refresh is given in seconds, so that should be 300.  It's the same effect as the meta tag, but now the server has to inject it into the http response instead of just barfing out the text in the aspx file.  Added mention of that header to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is

```
<Head>
<meta equiv="refresh" content="5">
</Head>
```

or use timer control to refresh a webpage for every five minutes
for example:
drag and drop timer control in form.aspx
and in form load add the code like below

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="6000" ontick="Timer1_Tick" />
```

form load

```
public void DoMagic()
{


}
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DoMagic();
Label1.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: ASP.NET timers are not that simple.  They cause a postback.  That means a bunch of javascript and (likely) some side-effects that the OP is probably not expecting or wanting.

Comment: i think it could be used within Ajax or even set ispostback to fix it

Comment: IsPostback will be true, yes.  It's still a lot more complex than the other ways suggested here, and requires being aware of the postback state of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
 window.setInterval(function () {
            // this will execute every 1 second

            methodCallOrAction();

        }, 1000);



function methodCallOrAction()
{
// u can call an url or do something here
}
```