# how to refresh page after 30 minutes automatically without run the project using c#(asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a C# asp.net application that I need to be refreshed a single page every 30 minutes automatically without run the project using c#(asp.net) .

Comment: what do yu mean by without run the project?

Comment: @ArunPratap i am working with hotel project and  get some online booking details with ajax response and then that response insert into my sql table, now i want to know how to get response in every after 30 minuts without refresh the page

Comment: refreshing a page and running project is two thing update your question according to your need and tag Ajax your question is different from your need give more clear information so that anyone can help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refresh page using c# int every five minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210056/how-to-refresh-page-using-c-sharp-int-every-five-minutes)

Answer (score 2):

Use Mata Tags

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="1800">
```

Other way is to use JavaScript:

> `setTimeout(function, milliseconds)` Executes a function, after
>   waiting a specified number of milliseconds.
>
> `setInterval(function, milliseconds)` Same as `setTimeout()`, but repeats the execution of
>   the function continuously.

```
setTimeout("location.reload(true);", timeout);
```

**Edit:** In reality, this is standard HTML functionality and nothing specific to **ASP.NET**. The same effect of auto-refresh would be seen whether it is an ASP.NET page or just a HTML page, or a page made in Java, PHP, ColdFusion, Perl or the like.

If you want to set the refresh time dynamically then that can be done in **ASP.NET** by adding server side code in the `Page_Load` function to set it like below:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "1800")
```

Comment: this is for open  project i want to make something like without having open page 
 on browser

Answer (score 1):

You should try this one in head tag -

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1800">
```

Comment: what , you should try?